# React and Unpermitted parameter

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, reactjs, dropzone.js

After setup the dropzone react with a simple rails api in the logs shows:

```
Processing by Api::UsersController#update as */*
21:03:10 web.1       |   Parameters: {"avatar"=>[{"preview"=>"blob:http://localhost:3000/4b4f28d6-cab3-46e5-a887-912580bbca1a"}], "access_token"=>"6jaabLFdUG-7jGuC_RvH2Q", "user"=>{"avatar"=>[{"preview"=>"blob:http://localhost:3000/4b4f28d6-cab3-46e5-a887-912580bbca1a"}]}}
21:03:10 web.1       | Can't verify CSRF token authenticity
21:03:10 web.1       |   User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."access_token" = ? LIMIT 1  [["access_token", "6jaabLFdUG-7jGuC_RvH2Q"]]
21:03:10 web.1       | Unpermitted parameter: avatar
21:03:10 web.1       |    (0.2ms)  begin transaction
21:03:10 web.1       |   User Exists (0.5ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE ("users"."username" = 'teste' AND "users"."id" != 1) LIMIT 1
21:03:10 web.1       |   User Exists (0.7ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE ("users"."name" = '1' AND "users"."id" != 1) LIMIT 1
21:03:10 web.1       |    (0.3ms)  commit transaction
21:03:10 web.1       |   Rendered text template (0.1ms)
21:03:10 web.1       | Completed 200 OK in 47ms (Views: 19.0ms | ActiveRecord: 2.0ms)
```

But in the controller the avatar params is permitted, so someone has any clue why this happening?

the dropzone code:

```
updateAvatar(file) {


    const request = new Request("http:/api/users/"+ auth.getToken(), {
      method: 'PUT',
      headers: new Headers({


        'Content-Type' : 'application/json',
        '_method'      : 'put',
        'content-type': 'multipart/form-data'        
      }),
      body: JSON.stringify({avatar: file})
    });

    return fetch(request).then(response => {
      return response.json();
    }).catch(error => {
      return error;
    });
  }


<Dropzone onDrop={this.updateAvatar}>
   <button>Try dropping some files here.</button>
 </Dropzone>
```

user controller

```
def update
      if @user.update_attributes(user_params)

        render text: "Account has been updated successfully", status: 200
      else
        render json: @user.errors, status: 422
      end
    end
     def user_params
            params.require(:user).permit( :avatar,:name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation)
          end
```

Answer (score 0):

Whitelist the params as follows:

```
params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, avatar: [:preview])
```

Also, the Rails app is not able to verify the CSRF token.

Add the following in your `ApplicationController`

```
protect_from_forgery with: :null_session
```

You can read more about CSRF from [here](https://medium.com/rubyinside/a-deep-dive-into-csrf-protection-in-rails-19fa0a42c0ef)

Comment: Kartikey Tanna tank you for your reply. yes i'm white listening the avatar but not the preview.
and the preview is automatic on the dropzone

Comment: Kartikey Tanna tank you for your reply. yes i'm white listening the avatar but not the preview.
and the preview is automatic on the dropzone

Comment: That won't work either. @lula's strong params `require(:user)` require that `avatar` (as well as `name`, `email`, etc.) need to be nested under a parent key `user`. So, you'd want to pass something like `{"user" => {"avatar"=>"..."}}`

Comment: @vich the params are nested under "user" key. Just scroll the params input.

Comment: @lula please check out the updated answer. Copy and paste the code `params.requrie` code in your controller

Comment: @KartikeyTanna i alreay tried but now shows this error:





 User Load (1.6ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."access_token" = ? LIMIT 1  [["access_token", "6jaabLFdUG-7jGuC_RvH2Q"]]
23:49:29 web.1       |    (0.2ms)  begin transaction
23:49:29 web.1       |    (1.0ms)  rollback transaction
23:49:29 web.1       | Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 102ms (ActiveRecord: 12.2ms)
23:49:29 web.1       | 
23:49:29 web.1       | TypeError (no implicit conversion of nil into String):
23:49:29 web.1       |   app/controllers/api/users_controller.rb:45:in `update'

Comment: @KartikeyTanna you're right - `avatar` is being passed in twice. @lula your issue now is that you're passing the value for `avatar` as an array when you specify the strong param to accept an object `avatar: [:preview]`.

Comment: @vich so the problem is with the dropzone. because, is seems automatic